# Spring - Bean executes method twice

Tags: java, spring

The below method refreshDatasets is executed twice when I run the app. Any idea what I messed up with the configuration of Spring (annotation based)?

**SchedulingTasks**

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingTasks {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Autowired
    public TestClass testclass;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    public void refreshDatasets() {
        testclass.simpleTest();
        System.out.println("The time is now " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

**TestClass**

```
@Component
public class TestClass {
    public void simpleTest() {
        System.out.println("FINISHED");
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.some.analytics.scripts",
excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter (
        type= FilterType.ANNOTATION,
        value=Configuration.class)})
public class ScriptsConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer p =  new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        p.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);

        return p;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Scripts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ScriptsConfig.class);

        SchedulingTasks schedulingTasks = ctx.getBean(SchedulingTasks.class);
        schedulingTasks.refreshDatasets();
    }
}
```

When running the main method, I get the following output:

```
FINISHED The time is now 11:08:39 
FINISHED The time is now 11:08:39
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `@EnableScheduling` annotation, Spring creates a `TaskExecutor` in the background. This will schedule all the `@Scheduled` methods. In the case of methods with  `fixedDelay`, they will be fired instantly (unless `initialDelay` is set).

You are also programatically executing the task, so you have two executions:

- The one executed by Spring
- The one executed in the main method.

You should remove the manual invocation, and everything should work as expected.

You can find more information in https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ and https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling-task-scheduler

Comment: Never would've guessed that it's related to the scheduling. Thanks a lot - removed my own method execution and indeed it still executed the method - this time only once. Thanks!